# Getting information on a specific computer in the network based on username

Tags: networking, dns

I was wondering if it is possible to get the IP Address or Hostname of a computer on my network given the logon username.

When I say this, I am referring to other users, whom, if I know their username, I can then get their IP/hostname. Is this possible?

I am looking for console commands such as: nslookup

Comment: You need some sort of Network Discovery/Scanner tools (eg. nmap) to do a network scan to find connected devices (IP / Hostname). But again that does absolutely nothing to do with having a username. It will simply do a scan for devices on the network.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Duplicating posts on several stackexchange servers are frowned upon and in general one should not do it. If you want to ask the question on another net stack, then ask the moderators to move the entire post/question to the new stack instead and they will do so if the question is relevant for the new stack.

Comment: @Mogget Oh. I didn't know, I apologize dearly. I didn't know I could contact moderators? Won't happen again, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very useful tool by Mark Russinovich, called psLoggedOn. You can find it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx)

Comment: Beautiful answer! Pretty much exactly what I need! Thanks!